# Random variable- demonstrations

Tags: probability

Could you help me with these demonstration ?

Suppose that X is an integer valued random variable, and let $m\in N$. 
Show that:

$\sum^\infty_{n=-\infty} {P(n < X \leq n+m)}= m$

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(x<X\leq x+a)dx = a$

PS: sorry for the mistakes

Regarding the first proposition , we're talking about a discrete distribution aren't we ?
While the second is a continuous distribution

Now I know that $F(x)= P(X\leq x)$, but can I also say  that $F(x)= \sum^\infty_{-\infty} {P(X\leq x)}$, or this last expression tends to 1 as $x\longrightarrow \infty$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made some effort.

Comment: You also need to edit the things you asked us to show to make sense. $n$ is the index of summation in the first one so doesn't make sense as the RHS. In the second $a$ and $x$ don't appear in the integrand or limits of the integral at all. Did you mean to replace $n$ with $x$ and $m$ with $a$ here?

Comment: Yeah.. I wasn't paying attention sorry.